# Need to form an array with elements that I input on html

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I'm having problems with my code. I'm trying to form an array with elements coming from html.

My html is this:

```
<h2>Write the name of a friend </h2>

<input id="friends" type="text"/> <input type="button" value="Add name" button onclick="enter()"/>
```

and my jquery is:

```
myArray =[];
function enter() {
var friend = $("#friends").val();
myArray.push(friend);
};
```

Thanks

Comment: dont you need somewere POST or GET to read values?

Comment: you haven't explained what problem is

Comment: i'm not sure if the code works. How can I see the array after I input the names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your code works. You just need to remove that extra `button` in `button onclick="enter()"/>`:

```
<input type="button" value="Add name" onclick="enter()"/>
```

*"How can I see the array after I input the names?"* It's up to you, you can just simply `alert()` and you'll see the current value of the array:  `alert(myArray);`. Or you can add a new element and show/output your array's value onclick. Also why not switch to unobtrusive way of handling events:

html:

```
<h2>Write the name of a friend </h2>
<input id="friends" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Add name">
<p id="output"></p>
```

jQuery:

```
myArray = [];
$('input[type="button"]').click(function () {
    var friend = $('#friends').val();
    myArray.push(friend);

    $('#output').text('My Friends: '+ myArray)//output myArray's value
    $('#friends').val('');//reset the input field
});
```

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/96WAX/).